# whysiyg save in php file

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am currently developing somthing like a CMS, but without using any database. A really big problem for me is how can you change (and later format content via tinymce (or similar) ) and then save it into a php file?

My configuration file for each page looks like this:

```
<?php 
$title = 'Title of the page';

$contenttitle = <<<HTML
Something like a short summary, displayed at the top
HTML;


$content = <<<HTML
main content
HTML;

$foldername = basename(__FILE__, '.php');
include '../template/standard/layout/index.php'; ?>
```

Now, I want to be able to open a script in the browser where I can select the file I want to edit and see text boxes with content of $title, $contenttitle and $content. 
So, in fact we open a file, look for these 3 variables, display their content and change them (overwrite the file).

How can this be solved?

Comment: Dont store it as php(also unsafe), store it as json or xml ect something you can easily retrieve and parse back into usable data.

Comment: Why is storing as php unsafe? So u mean I should store it as xml... but there's still the problem how u can edit this? Have never had to do sth like that before :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example approach that may help you:

1. Write a php/html file which will print out a form for you:

   <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="title" value=""/>

   <input type="text" name="contenttitle" value=""/>

   <textarea name="content">">

   <input type="submit" value="save"/>
   </form>
2. Handle your form in the php file:

   if (!empty($_POST)) {

   $result = array(
   'title' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['title']),
   'contenttitle' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['contenttitle']),
   'content' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['content'])
   );

   // save it to a file by serialiing
   $filename = uniqid().'.text'; // you may play around with file names, rewrite this line so it will suit your convention - you may use counter of the files

   file_put_content($filename, serialize($result));

   }
3. To retrieve file and print it use something like this:

   $file = $_GET['name'];
   $file = str_replace(array('/', '.', '\'), '', $file); // for security reasons

   $content = file_get_contents($file.'.text'); // note this is an example extension

   $data = unserialize($content);

   echo '<h1>'.$data['title'].'</h1>';

   echo '<h2>'.$data['contenttitle'].'</h2>';

   echo '<p>'.$data['content'].'</p>';

Comment: Note that your files won't be cross platform. As mentioned in comments for your question, xml would be better. Also - upvote if it helps you.